# Highcharts: convert string to an object with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts

I am querying data from a webservice and in the next step I try to parse the data in a format that is sufficient for highcharts:

```
var aData = response.d;
var arr = [];

for (i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
    arr.push("["+[aData[i].FileDate2.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), aData[i].AutoReleasedPct]+"]");
} 

arr = "[" + arr + "]";
//alert(arr);
```

When I alert the result, i get this:

```
[ [1502920800000, 85.714285714285], [1502834400000, 82.022471910112], [1502748000000, 100], [1502488800000, 100], [1502402400000, 100], [1502316000000, 100], [1502229600000, 94], [1502143200000, 96.774193548387] ]
```

However, for some reason it doesn't work when I push `arr` to a highchart container. But it works when I copy the result and create an object

```
dataseries3 = [[1502920800000, 85.714285714285], [1502834400000, 82.022471910112], [1502748000000, 100], [1502488800000, 100], [1502402400000, 100], [1502316000000, 100], [1502229600000, 94], [1502143200000, 96.774193548387]];
```

and then push it to highcharts by `ccontainer2(dataseries3);`

Why there is a difference between this methods? Its actually exactly the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **function** you created only a string which looks like this:

```
"[elem1,elem2]"
```

But you need an **array** `object` in order to render the `highchart`.

For this, you can use `JSON.parse()` method.

`JSON.parse` method **turns** a string(json) into a javascript **object**.

Short example:

```js
var string="[[1,2],[3,4]]";
var array = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(array);
```

You have to use it in the following way:

```
ccontainer2(JSON.parse(arr));
```

Another method is to create directly an **array**.

```
var aData = response.d;
var arr = [];

for (i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
    arr.push([aData[i].FileDate2.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), aData[i].AutoReleasedPct]);
}
```

Comment: that ccontainer2(JSON.parse(arr)); is working just perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have problem here

arr.push(**"["+**[aData[i].FileDate2.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), aData[i].AutoReleasedPct]**+"]"**);

You just need array of arrays `[ [1,2], [2,3] ]`

```
 var aData = response.d;
    var arr = [];

    for (i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
        arr.push([aData[i].FileDate2.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), aData[i].AutoReleasedPct]);
    }
```

or you can use

```
[ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 3: y: 4} ]
```